# Software to make youtube audio easier to sleep to

Tags: audio, music, youtube, bluetooth

Sometimes I like to listen to audio from a youtube playlist with my bluetooth headset to help me fall asleep. Like a bedtime story.

I run into these problems.

1. The volume of sounds from the within a single youtube video can be uneven (a loud dubstep intro when the rest of the video volume is low for example) so the unevenness of the volume wakes me up.
2. Different youtube videos have different volumes. So one video in a playlist may be very loud whereas the next one could be very quiet. The uneveness wakes me up.
3. The volume of the sound does not gradually decrease. The laptop doesn't turn off on its own. So when I do fall asleep, there is sound still playing and light coming from the laptop and my sleep is not as deep as if the sound would eventually go silent.
4. The Bluetooth headset will eventually disconnect after a long enough period of time. Or run out of battery. And I get either a loud or buzzing notification from the headset that wakes me up. The act of moving my arms/hands to turn off the Bluetooth headset wakes me up a bit and the voice sound it makes "POWER OFF" when I turn it off also wakes me up a bit.

A person reading a bedtime story would not have these problems.

**What software can address these or even just some of these easily for a person who isn't good with computers?**

I use a windows 8 laptop and a Samsung android phone and an ipad air 2

> Why youtube? It has an easy to search, massive amount of content. Why not stick to audiobooks on cassette or CD? I do sometimes- but there's much less content, need to pay for more content each time, and still doesn't fix problems of 1. no gradually decreasing audio 2. can't use bluetooth headset so you risk pulling the cassette player or CD player off the table as you move in the night. I live in an apartment and gotta use a headset / earbuds except nights I happen to go to bed very early